# Xcode: pod showing wrong Swift version after updating pod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

When I ran "Build", Xcode showed me the error "SWIFT_VERSION '3.2' is unsupported..." for one of my Pods, which, sure enough, was using Swift version 3.2.

I updated the problem Pod to a newer version that specifies Swift 5.0 in its `.swift-version` file, but when I run "Build", Xcode still shows me the same error, which claims that the problem Pod is using Swift 3.2.

I've tried cleaning the build folder, deleting the Pod cache and reinstalling all CocoaPods for the project, and quitting and restarting Xcode, but none of that solved this problem.  How do I get Xcode to recognize the Swift version in the Pod folder?

Comment: Check what the actual value of `SWIFT_VERSION` is in the target configuration (in the Pods project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to open the Project Navigator, click on "Pods", select the problem Pod, and **in "Build Settings", change the Swift Language Version.**
[image: Xcode screenshot]
Thank you, @Claus Jørgensen for pointing me to the answer!